# div pushes down buttons (div and buttons have the exact same css attributes)

Tags: html, css

There is a div containing 1 div and 3 buttons where the buttons and the inner div have exactly the same css attributes, margin padding and border are set to 0 and the height of the buttons and the inner div is the same as the outer div. Why does the inner div pushes the buttons down?

```css
.extras {
  width:100%;
  height:56px;
  background-color:purple;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.extras button {
  display:inline-block;
  width:110px;
  height:55px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:auto;
}

#test_div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:110px;
  height:55px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="extras">
  <div id="test_div">woops</div>
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.extras button { vertical-align:top; }
```

```css
.extras {
  width:100%;
  height:55px;
  background-color:purple;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.extras button {
  display:inline-block;
  width:110px;
  height:55px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:auto;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#test_div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:110px;
  height:55px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "extras">
  <div id="test_div">woops</div>
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you flex if you want to remove extra CSS. or add `verticle-align: top` to `.extras button'

```css
.extras
{
  width:100%;
  height:56px;
  background-color:purple;
  text-align: center;
    display:flex;
}

.extras button
{
  width:110px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#test_div
{
  width:110px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor:pointer;
     /* if you want center text */
     display:flex;
     align-items:center;
     justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "extras">
    <div id="test_div">woops</div>
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
    <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `display: flex`

```css
.extras {
  width:100%;
  height:56px;
  background-color: purple;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  display:inline-flex;
  width:110px;
  height:55px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.bdr_0{
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="extras">
  <div class="button">woops</div>
  <button class="button bdr_0">button 1</button>
  <button class="button bdr_0">button 2</button>
  <button class="button bdr_0">button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first i wanna say that if you wanna add the same style to a few elements so you can write the both elements split with `,` on one style. like this:

```
  .extras button, #text_div { ....  }
```

about your quetion: the buttons go down because he display it inline bottom of a div with a text inside the buttosns. for fix it you can use:

```
  vertical-align: top;
```

the only thing that you still have to do is make the text on the div appear in the vertical center, like a buttons. for this you can set the line height as a div height. in your case it 55px. like this:

```
 line-height: 55px;
```

so the full answer is:

html:

```
<div class="extras">
    <div id="test_div">woops</div>
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
    <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
    .extras {
        width: 100%;
        height: 56px;
        background-color: purple;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #test_div,
    .extras button {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 110px;
        height: 55px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: auto;
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 55px;
    }
```

hope i help :)